# 'Less Than' Escape Character in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to do the following

```
tell application "Finder"
    open location "smb://user:password@filesystem/folder"
end tell
```

However the password has a '<' in it and it seems to break the whole command.  Running the script does nothing.  When I remove the '<' the script runs but of course the logon fails.  I tried doing \< but it didn't work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Finder not understanding what to do with the URL. If you escape the < with %3c, it will work. Also, if you're connecting to a Windows computer or otherwise have to provide a domain name with the user, do it like smb://domain;user:password@host/share. I learned about this from [this page](http://www.smilingsouls.net/Blog/20110526100731.html).

Comment: Just what I was looking for, I had a few other characters too.  It is the %<ascii code as a hex value> just in case anyone looks this up